# What is best approach to securing an ASP.NET Core Web API when the client is an ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an old .NET Framework MVC application. I'd like to put new business logic in an NET 6.0 Web API. The old MVC app uses cookie based authentication.

Below is part of the ConfigureAuth method. I'm including this so the authentication mechanism is clear and you don't rely on my rather poor understanding of this area in specifying what mechanism is used.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(Context.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

I'd like the ASP.NET Core Web API to be only accessible by authenticated users of the MVC app. I'd like the web API to know the identity of the user that has been authenticated with the MVC app. I'd like the Web API to be callable from the browser and from controllers of the MVC app. How do I approach this? I have spent time browsing topics in this area and am quite confused.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, are you saying that article provides the means to do what I want? It doesn't look promising, as it discusses microservices and API gateway. My problem is that masses of articles and support pages exist on authentication and I don't where to focus my attention. Nothing I have found looks like it discusses my problem.

Comment: There's no best approach for securing, you should refer to what Robert provided and check your own requirement then choose one method for your project. For example, I'm familar with azure ad, so I used to integrating azure ad as the authentication for api. Maybe you are familar with Azure api management, then you can also use Azure apim.Maybe you only need to create a demo for learning, then you can easily add a intercept in your code to check if the incoming request contain some specific request header which is defined by yourself... Or I may misunderstand in some place?